# Is there a way to read xlsx file stored in s3 from a glue job?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, xlsx, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

My task requires to read xlsx file stored in s3 bucket from a glue job. I have looked into many places and they say glue job doesnt have a support to do so.
Is there any alternate way to do it? or Glue is just not the solution for such task.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in Glue and I would use pandas for it.  Note, Glue runtimes come with Pandas, but since you're dealing with excel you'll need to install openpyxl.  See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html) for how to do that.

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

import pandas as pd

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

df = pd.read_excel('s3://my-bucket/glue_excel_data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

# ...

job.commit()
```